# how to implement search function in Qt Quick folderListmodel ??

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

I want implement search functioning to my music player totally written in Qml 
. In my case i initiated a qml Filedialog to get folder from filesystem and then i used folderListModel to list them through ListView .
I want search through the list any clue how can i achieve this ????

Please don't suggest to use c++ . and also not suggest me to use `nameFilters :["*."]`  in foldelistmodel cause it wont work it only filter according to extension of file not the file name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually `nameFilters` does allow to filter by filename. Using a kind of hack, it is even possible to make it case insensitive.

Here is an ugly but working example:

```
import QtQuick 2.3
import QtQuick.Controls 1.2
import Qt.labs.folderlistmodel 2.1

Item {
    width: 300
    height: 300

    FolderListModel
    {
        id: folderListModel
    }

    function updateFilter()
    {
        var text = filterField.text
        var filter = "*"
        for(var i = 0; i<text.length; i++)
            if(!caseSensitiveCheckbox.checked)
                filter+= "[%1%2]".arg(text[i].toUpperCase()).arg(text[i].toLowerCase())
            else
                filter+= text[i]
        filter+="*"
        print(filter)
        folderListModel.nameFilters = [filter]
    }

    Row
    {
        spacing: 5
        Text {text:"Filter"}
        TextField
        {
            id: filterField
            onTextChanged: updateFilter()
        }

        Text {text:"Case Sensitive"}
        CheckBox
        {
            id: caseSensitiveCheckbox
            checked: false
            onCheckedChanged:updateFilter()
        }
    }

    ListView
    {
        anchors.fill: parent
        anchors.topMargin: 30
        model:folderListModel
        delegate: Text{text: model.fileName}
    }

}
```

Comment: thanks man it works like charm :) u are life saver for me i been digging this from more then a week i tried everything and you came like god with just 56 lines of code with a working example thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

Use [DelegateModel](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-models-delegatemodel.html) :

> with [DelegateModelGroup](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-models-delegatemodelgroup.html) to sort and filter delegate items.

Assume that you have a function to filter files using filename,

```
function willBeShownOnView(filename){ /* ... */ }
```

You can extend this function by passing more roles (`fileSize`, `fileIsDir`, ...) or filter string entered by user if you need, and implement the filtering logic within this function.

Next, create a `DelegateModel` with a `filterGroup`:

```
DelegateModel {
    id: delegateModel
    model: FolderListModel{id: folderModel}
    groups: [
        DelegateModelGroup {
            name: "filterGroup"; includeByDefault: true
        }
    ]
    filterOnGroup: "filterGroup"
    delegate: MyFileDisplayComponent{/* ... */}

    function applyFilter(){ /* see below */}
}
```

As `includeByDefault: true`, all items in `folderModel` are included in the `filterGroup`. And when we `applyFilter`, some items should be removed from this group. For example,

```
function applyFilter(){
    var numberOfFiles = folderModel.count;
    for (var i = 0; i < numberOfFiles; i++){
        var fileName = folderModel.get(i, "fileName");

        if (willBeShownOnView(fileName)){items.addGroups(i, 1, "filterGroup");}
        else {items.removeGroups(i, 1, "filterGroup");}
    }
}
```

After `applyFilter` is called, only files that passes `willBeShownOnView` is added to the `filterGroup`. And the property `filterOnGroup: "filterGroup"` says the delegate model contains only items within the `filterGroup`. Therefore, we can use a simple ListView to display the result:

```
ListView { 
    model: delegateModel
    //...
}
```